# Fetching results from more than one IRepository

Tags: orchardcms

I have a list of Users and Orders.

```
public class UserRecord
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrderRecord
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

I have two repositories - IRepository and IRepository. How can I join the two and fetch the result, like this?

SELECT UserRecord.UserId, Name, OrderId
FROM UserRecord, OrderRecord
WHERE UserRecord.UserId = OrderRecord.UserId

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HQL API that is on ContentManager instead. Repository is for simple CRUD operations on a single table.

Comment: To use ContentManager, both user and order record must be content parts? Is there a HQL sample query for joining two tables/content parts?

Comment: Hql should in principle enable any query that you could do with regular nHibernate. There are examples in Projector and in HqlExpressionTest.cs.

You can also grab the nHibernate session directly and do arbitrary Hql or even SQL queries from there. There is an example of that in the OrchardPo module.

Comment: I am getting an exception when I try to use ISession. `code`public MyController(...ISession session ...`code`. I get this exception - Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with policy 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFinderWrapper' on type 'MyController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Constructor 'Void .ctor(Orchard.Data.IRepository`1[UserRecord], Orchard.Data.IRepository`1[OrderRecord], NHibernate.ISession)' parameter resolution failed at parameter 'NHibernate.ISession session'.

Comment: Because ISession doesn't derive from IDependency. That's not how you get the session. If you had looked at OrchardPo, you would have seen that what you need to inject is an ISessionLocator. once you have that, you can call For on it to get the actual session object.

Comment: I tried this,
_session = _sessionLocator.For(typeof(UserRecord))
IQuery qry = _session.CreateQuery("from UserRecord as user where user.UserId = 1");

I get an error saying UserRecord is not mapped.

Comment: That means that your record has not been picked up and mapped for some reason. Could be that you didn't put it in Models.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice this comment until now, looks like stackoverflow doesn't display more than 5 comments by default. Both the classes are inside Models folder.

Comment: I don't know then. Oh, one more thing you might want to try is give those records an Id column (and really call it Id). Oh and one thing I have neglected to ask: you did create the tables in the database from a migration, right?

Comment: It works now. I added fully qualified namespace, instead of from UserRecord... from MyModule.Models.UserRecord...